# Minimize $|Ax-b|_2^2$ subject to $|x|_2^2 = \gamma$

Tags: optimization, normed-spaces

> Minimize $|Ax-b|_2^2$ subject to $|x|_2^2 = \gamma$. Using the SVD decomposition of the matrix $A = USV^T$.

Without the constraint, it is just an euclidian minimization problem with $x^{*} = (A^{-1}A)^TA^Tb$. However, I don't know what to do in this case. Can you help me?

Comment: You may want to separate the cases $\|x^\ast\|_2^2=\gamma$ (in which case it is solved), $\|x^\ast\|_2^2<\gamma$ and $\|x^\ast\|_2^2>\gamma$, those three problem are pretty different.